# How to add number of days to a date, consider only business days (i.e. ignore weekends)?

Tags: excel, date, openoffice-calc, dayofweek, weekday

I'm trying to create a formula to calculate the *n-th* **Business Date** (only Monday to Friday are business days).
For simplicity's sake, holidays are not important; only weekends should be ignored.

For example:

```
   +------------------------------------------------------------------
   |   A                B                     C
   +------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  Starting Date    Business-Day Number   Business Date
2  |  06-Jun-2012      0                     06-Jun-2012
3  |  06-Jun-2012      1                     07-Jun-2012
4  |  06-Jun-2012      2                     08-Jun-2012
5  |  06-Jun-2012      3                     11-Jun-2012    <-- June 9th (Sat) and 10th (Sun) are skipped
6  |  06-Jun-2012      4                     12-Jun-2012
...
```

The formula would be used to fill **Column C** above.
The only solution I could come up with involves vlookup on a table of working days, which I found a bit cumbersome.

Any ideas how I could go for it in a single formula?

(it can be on Excel or OpenOffice-Calc)

Comment: Lookup is your best solution, because it will cope with holidays easily, it's simple and easily extensible. A formula will be a right PIA.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Excel WORKDAY function does this, e.g. this formula in C2

`=WORKDAY(A2,B2)`

you can also add a holiday range, for example with holidays listed in H2:H10 make that

`=WORKDAY(A2,B2,H$2:H$10)`

WORKDAY is a built-in function in Excel 2007 and later versions - in earlier versions you need to enable `Analysis ToolPak` addin

Comment: It seems to work fine with whole numbers, but what if my duration contains half- and other fractions of a day?

Comment: This works in Libreoffice too (at least on LO 7)

Answer (score 4):

In LibreOffice Calc:

```
C1=A1+INT(B1/5)*7+MOD(B1,5)+(IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)+MOD(B1,5)>5,2,0))
```